# Is it possible to revert a Code Workbook to a previous version?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-workbooks

I'd like to recover an accidentally modified workbook to a previous version.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to revert a Code Workbook to a previous version. Reach out through your customer support channels for additional information.

If you're using Code Workbook to build a data pipeline, consider using Code Workbook templates or migrating your pipeline to Code Repositories, both of which support versioning out of the box.